# Laravel Advance Search filter Not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have try to pass different parameters in search query but it is not working it showing me wrong result. I have united states country in my data base so i want to search like when ever any one search anything first come with US result then other country result. It is getting result randomly from the data base.

Controller Function Code :

```
$data['countries']      = Countries::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->where('id', '!=', '231')->get();   
        $data['categories']     = categories::get();   

        $query = UserProfiles::join('users', 'users_profiles.user_id', '=', 'users.id');

        $query->join('countries','users_profiles.country','=','countries.id');
        $query->join('states','users_profiles.state','=','states.id');


        if(!empty($request->category)){ 
            $query->where('users.member_type',$request->category);
        }

        if(!empty($request->country)){ 
            $query->where('users_profiles.country', $request->country);
        }

        if(!empty($request->state)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.state', $request->state);
        }

        if(!empty($request->type)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.type_surrogacy', $request->type);
        }

        if(!empty($request->city)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.city', $request->city);
        }

        if(!empty($request->willing_to)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.willing_to_assist', $request->willing_to);
        }

        if(!empty($request->languages)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.languages', $request->languages);
        }

        if(!empty($request->country)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.country', $request->country);
        }

        if(!empty($request->education)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.education', $request->education);
        }

        if(!empty($request->smoker)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.smoker', $request->smoker);
        }

        if(!empty($request->hair_color)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.hair_color', $request->hair_color);
        }

        if(!empty($request->eye_color)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.eye_color', $request->eye_color);
        }

        if(!empty($request->marital_status)){
            $query->where('users_profiles.marital_status', $request->marital_status);
        }

        $query->select('users.*','countries.name as country','states.name as state');

        $data['search_results'] = $query->paginate(15);
```

Below is a view code which i am using to list all the data

View Code:

```
@foreach($search_results as $results)

{{$results->first_name.' '.$results->last_name}}

@endforeach

{!! $search_results->appends(Request::except('page'))->render() !!}
```

Comment: And what is problem/question?

Comment: This is working code i want share this with community so this will help some one in future